# Is there a way to force an onAppear to update again?

Tags: swiftui, onappear

I have an onAppear statement which is working fine when the view first loads:

```
.onAppear(){
    getData(from: "https://api.data/address/\(dataSettings.dataname)/storage/\(dataSettings.storagename)") { result in
        self.content = result
    }
}
```

However, when the user navigates away to a settings page and changes some information, this onAppear (correctly) does not update again.  Is there something I can replace this with to cause the content to update if the settings information is updated?

Comment: How about changing `dataSetting` type to @State and @Binding on setting page and fetching again when it changes?

Comment: It contains a class (ObserveableObject), and each item there uses @AppStorage.

Comment: There is too much missing to answer this question, what specifically is causing the redraw? Are you recreating the View? More often than more you can “fix” this by just understanding what SwiftUI is doing.

Comment: That's the issue - there is nothing to cause the redraw.  I do not want to redraw the page - I'd rather place this inside some type of function that updates, but then that leads to errors with sending the result to 'content'.

Comment: You are doing something to cause it to redraw…

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You can use `AppStorage` outside of a `View`. In fact, Apple specifically updated it so that it would work with `ObservableObject`. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_5-release-notes

Comment: @Alligator Assuming your deployment target is high enough, it sounds like you want `task` instead of `onAppear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.task(id: dataSettings)` will happen on appear and when settings change